# How to add more rows in table using javascript/jquery and with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on list generator replacements for teachers.

I have some columns in my table like these for example:

```
<div id="formReplacements">
                <table id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Day</td><td>Class</td><td>Lesson number</td><td>Lesson</td><td>Teacher</td><td>Room</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="day" name="day">
<?php
                                if (date(N) >= 6)
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="'.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next Monday")).'">Monday ('.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next monday")).')</option>';
                                    echo '<option value="'.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next Tuesday")).'">Tuesday ('.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next tuesday")).')</option>';
                                    echo '<option value="'.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next Wednesday")).'">Wednesday ('.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next wednesday")).')</option>';
                                }
//some more code in php here, irrelevant to the question...
                                ?>
                                <option value="another" name="another" id="another">Another...</option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            var selectmenu=document.getElementById("day")
                            selectmenu.onchange=function(){ //run some code when "onchange" event fires
                             var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]
                             if (chosenoption.value=="another"){
                              var test = window.prompt("Write the date","");
                              document.getElementById('another').value = test;
                              document.getElementById('another').text = test;
                             }
                            }
                            </script>
                        </td>
                        <td>
//etc...
```

So, as you can see this code generates a form with a table and when you select "Another..." it will show javascript dialogbox with textbox, so you can enter another date.

But I wanted to be able to add more rows dynamically into my table so I added this code:

```
<HEAD>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var counter=1;
                $("#add_replacement").click(function () {
                    counter++;
                    myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
                    myTable.innerHTML = myTable.innerHTML+'<tr><td><select id="day'+counter+'" name="day'+counter+'"><?php
                                if (date(N) >= 6)
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="'.dateV('j f Y',strtotime('next Monday')).'">Monday ('.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next monday")).')</option>';
                                    echo '<option value="'.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next Tuesday")).'">Tuesday ('.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next tuesday")).')</option>';
                                    echo '<option value="'.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next Wednesday")).'">Wednesday ('.dateV('j f Y',strtotime("next wednesday")).')</option>';
                                }
//...
                    ?><option value="another" name="another" id="another">Another...</option></select><script type="text/javascript">var selectmenu=document.getElementById("day'+counter+'");selectmenu.onchange=function(){ var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]; if (chosenoption.value=="another"){var test = window.prompt("Write the date","");document.getElementById("another").value = test;document.getElementById("another").text = test;}}<\/script>';
                    myTable.innerHTML = myTable.innerHTML+'</td><td><select name="classes"><optgroup label="Classes I">';
                    document.getElementById('number_of_replacements').value = counter;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </HEAD>
```

and:

```
<input type="button" id="add_replacement" value="Add new replacement..." />
```

But it's not working properly - after adding new replacement and selecting "Another..." from the optionbox I don't get javascript dialogbox where I could write the date.

And btw. I think that what I have just done is bad practise, I think there must be other ways to solve this problem with adding new replacements with javascript inside.

Sorry for my English errors. If anything is unclear, please ask.

Defozo

Comment: I don't think you can use php within javascript like that.

Comment: `echo`? That's not JavaScript ...

Comment: PHP within JavaScript works good.
If, however, it is not widely used, then what is?

Comment: php and javascript run in completely different environments. php on server and js in browser. It seems you aren't considering that

Comment: This code is saved in *.php file and it's runned on WebServ.
I don't want to add php code dynamically in new rows.

Comment: no idea what your last comment means

Comment: Did you mean `date("N") >= 6`? And did you mean something like `"day" + current` for the `getElementById` inside the second `<script>` tag? The output of the PHP code, and the subsequent HTML that you want to place in `myTable.innerHTML` will be on multiple lines, and *might not* be considered (someone should verify this). Try viewing the source of the resultant page, and see if this is a problem.